# Firestore security rule to restrict writes to fields for both set and update?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write some Firestore security rules that only allow users to write to certain fields in their documents (e.g. email, gender, preferredName, address).

I wrote the following write rule to restrict access to specific fields:

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read: if userIsAuthenticated() 
                     && userIsAccessingTheirData(userId);

      // Users can always write to specific fields                
      allow write: if userIsAuthenticated() 
                     && userIsAccessingTheirData(userId)
                     && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["preferredName","gender", "email", "address"]);
```

The rules works well for when we call **userDoc.set** in code, but it doesn't work when we call **userDoc.update**.

Using the Firestore rules emulator, I can see that when we call "set" the  `request.resource.data.keys()` only has the fields that are being passed in the call, but when I call "update" all the fields of the document are in the key collection :-( which makes it impossible to filter.

Is there a way to write a security rule that restricts the fields like above that works for both set and update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.resource` variable represents the document as it will exist after the operation succeeds (*if* it succeeds of course). So `request.resource` does *not* just contain the fields that are being updated, but also the other values from the existing document.

It's always been possible to check if a field is being updated by comparing `request.resource.data.fieldname` with `resource.data.fieldname`.

But recently a new `affectedKeys()` function was introduced to security rules that shows just the delta:

```
// This rule only allows updates where "a" is the only field affected
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```

Also see the [release notes for Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules).

Comment: Thanks Frank for the explanation of the behavior of `request resource` and the pointer to the affectedkeys.

Answer (score 0):

you can access document fields using request.resource.data.{field}

for example if you want to restrict updating dob :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure all cities have a positive population and
    // the name is not changed
    match /users/{user} {
      allow update: if request.resource.data.dob == resource.data.dob;
    }
  }
}
```

This means that the document can be updated as long as dob hasn't changed which is what we are trying to achieve.